# How to Import other language data to Firestore from json?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I aware about How to import data from JSON to RTDB and then import it to Cloud Firestore through node.js but I have a different issue.

My database is in other language (Gujarati - Indian Language) and when I import it to Firebase RTDB, its convert to question marks. I know that Firebase supports this language but when I import it, it's converted to question marks.

Also, I want the document id when it's imported. Currently, its document id is 1,2,3,4...

I tried to import it through node.js but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer within a minute :) I just copy json as plain text in code editor and import it to RTDB and it works. Thanks

Comment: Oh! You just did as a simple way.